# Laravel 5 - Many to many relations - Getting the pivot data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Hi I have the following database struture

`User` has two type of users `Artist` and `Fans` and has two tables `artists` and `fans` to store the unique data

User model

```
public function artist()
    {
            return $this->hasOne('App\Artist');
    }
public function fans()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Fan');
    }
```

There will be multiple Fans for Artists so I have created a *pivot* table to store the relations

Artist model

```
public function fans() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Fan');
    }
```

Fan Model

```
public function artist() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Artist');
    }
```

pivot table schema

```
Schema::create('artist_fan', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('artist_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('fan_id')->unsigned();
            //
        });
```

I have used the following code but result is an empty Collection

```
$user = auth()->user();
dd($user->artist->fans);
```

output

```
Collection {#263 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

Please help me to retrieve the fans of the current logged in Artist. Also doing CRUD operations to the pivot table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$artists = \App\Artist::has('fans') // Artists who has fans
                      ->with('fans') // load fans
                      ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id) // Where artist.user_id = logged in user id
                      ->get(); // Get all artists

if($artists->count())
{
    $fans = $artists->fans; // Get fans
}
```

Comment: if($artists->count() > 0)
        {
            $fans = $artists[0]->fans;
        }

Comment: Opps! I made a mistake, it should be `if($artists->count())` :-)